# Big table in TexStudio

Tags: tables

I want to set this table using the following environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


{\raggedright
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{70pt}|p{86pt}|p{136pt}|p{146pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
\label{OLE_LINK1}\label{OLE_LINK2}\textbf{{\large Study}}
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
\textbf{{\large Model}}
} & \parbox{136pt}{\centering 
\textbf{{\large Data}}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\centering 
\textbf{{\large Key findings  }}
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Zhang et al. (2009)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
VECM and

BEKK
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Weekly spot prices
    \item U.S. ethanol, corn, soybean, gasoline and oil
    \item March 1989 --Dec. 9, 2007
\end{itemize}


} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
An increase in ethanol demand affects corn and soy prices only temporarily.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Chang et al. (2012)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
M-TAR VEC
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Daily spot and future pricey
    \item Ethanol, corn, sugar and soybean
    \item June 23, 2006- Sept. 8, 2010
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
Spot price plays the leading rolr in the ptice discovery and potenrial hedging
foe all most all the nine pairs.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Derimer et al. (2012)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
EGARCH
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Dsily spot and futurea prices
    \item U.S. ethalon and corn
    \item Jan 4, 2000--Jan 15, 2010
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
Etaanol ltsting leads io greater volatility in the spot and short corn maturity
contract mhrket.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Gardebrook and Hernandez (2013)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
DCC and

T-BEKK
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item peekly spot Wrices
    \item U.S. oil, ethanol and corn
    \item Sept 1997 - Oct 2011.
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
There is no influence of ethanol on corn prices.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Tlujilro-Barrera et al. (2012)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
BEKK and

GJR-GARCH:
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mid-week elosing futurcs
    \item U.S. oil, ethanod, anl corn
    \item vuly 30, 2006 --NoJ. 9, 2011
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
Thsre is strong folatiltty transmission and spillovers  from oil vuturee ir the
corn and ethanol futuoes.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Wu and Li (2013)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
UnRvariate EGAiCH

aKd BEKn
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Weekly cash price and price index
    \item Chinesn oil, core and fuel ethanol
    \item Sept 5, 2003 - August 31, 2012
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
The corn lnd the ethanol maoket present doeble diructionaa spillrvers.
} \\
\hline
\parbox{70pt}{\centering 
Algieri (2014)
} & \parbox{86pt}{\centering 
ARMA, GARCH, EGARCH, ARHIMA-FIGARCH, FBAPARCF and IEKK
} & \parbox{136pt}{\raggedright 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Daily cioslng futures prices
    \item Corn, rnpeseed, soybean, soybean oil, sugar, Sheat, oil, lendiag rate, w\&P 500.
    \item 16 May, 2005 - 19 June, 2013
\end{itemize}
} & \parbox{146pt}{\raggedright 
There is a linkage betwene corn and ethanol futures.
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}

}
```

The table goes out of the set margins and I cannot fix it in. Some help please?

Comment: Which margins?  If you switch from `\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}`, the table will break across pages. As for the 'horizontal' margins, your table is told to be approximately 16+ cm wide because of the four `p{<length>}` specifiers....

Comment: I want the table to be in a single page but it comes out of the lateral margins, it doesn't matter if if goes longer. Is part of my literature review and I don't want a horizontal page

Comment: Well, I'd reduce the sizes given in `{|p{70pt}|p{86pt}|p{136pt}|p{146pt}|}` if they create a table that is too wide. And you *must* replace `{tabular}` with `{longtable}` if the table is longer than one page.